# gRPC (Cpp) Streaming - What happens if one side hangs or forgets to close the stream during grpc_impl::ServerReaderWriter::Read?

Tags: grpc

I am going through the gRPC cpp examples trying to learn. I noticed as I debug the streaming example, that the call on the server to grpc_impl::ServerReaderWriter::Read blocks until the other side writes or the stream ends.

How are we supposed to make the server robust enough that it can handle a client that hung or forgot to close the stream after it sent initial messages?

Maybe it makes an RPC call and streams me three messages, but never closes.
There doesn't seem to be a version of this call with a timeout.

Isn't my entire communication thread to all clients blocked in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServerReaderWriter::Read()` is part of the C++ sync API, so all the calls block by design.  If you want asynchronous behavior, you can switch to the C++ async API, although it is significantly harder to use.

If you're concerned only about the case of a client forgetting to close a stream, though, you can probably solve that specific case without using the async API.  Before you start a read, you can set a timer in another thread which will call `ServerContext::TryCancel()` to cancel the stream if the read has not succeeded within some timeout.  That should cause the read to return and the stream to be closed.

BTW, note that in the sync API, each request handler runs in its own thread, so having one stream's request handler blocking in a read does not affect any other stream that the server is processing.  So if that's all you're worried about, you probably don't need to do anything at all -- the blocking read is fine as-is.